# MySQL error 150, cannot create table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1005

I'm having trouble creating a table and I don't understand what's wrong. phpMyAdmin sets the error indicator next to the PRIMARY KEY declaration... I don't get why this is wrong...

This table is a child table, which has a one-to-many identifying relationship with another table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ruilen`.`Voorwerpen` (
`voorwerpen_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`naam` VARCHAR( 45 ) NOT NULL ,
`beschrijving` VARCHAR( 45 ) NULL ,
`Gebruikers_gebruiker_id` INT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `voorwerpen_id` , `Gebruikers_gebruiker_id` ) ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Voorwerpen_Gebruikers1` FOREIGN KEY ( `Gebruikers_gebruiker_id` ) REFERENCES `ruilen`.`Gebruikers` (
`gebruiker_id`
) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1005 - Can't create table 'ruilen.voorwerpen' (errno: 150)
```

EDIT: this is all the documentation on the error code I can find: [Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_cant_create_table)

EDIT2: *pic removed*

EDIT3:

```
CREATE TABLE `gebruikers` (
 `gebruiker_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `naam` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `straat` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `gemeente` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `mail` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `beschrijving` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`gebruiker_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check that `Gebruikers_gebruiker_id` and `Gebruikers`.`gebruiker_id` have same datatype.

Also check that `Gebruikers`.`gebruiker_id` is a `PRIMARY KEY` in `Gebruikers`

**Update:**

You have `ON DELETE SET NULL` defined, while your `Gebruikers_gebruiker_id` is defined as `NOT NULL`.

Fix it (change to `ON DELETE CASCADE` or just remove the clause) and you'll be able to create the reference.

Comment: pic added for more info, what you said seems to be the case.

Comment: Could you please run this statement: `SHOW CREATE TABLE Gebruikers` and post its output here?

Comment: Done. I wonder if I need to set the gebruiker_id to unique... but MySQL workbench doesn't seem to have that option...

Comment: @WebDevHobo: `gebruiker_id` is a `PRIMARY KEY`, this implies `UNIQUE`. The real problem is `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Comment: Thanks, most of mistake `add foreign key` is at `set null`. They forget to set the field to allow `null`.

Answer (score 4):

Im my case its typically because of a datatype mismatch. Remember if it is an int check that both are either **unsigned** or not

Answer (score 2):

This is'nt much a buggy characteristic of mysql.
There can be two possible reasons for this!
1) the datatypes of the PK and the FK dont match.
2) This error can come up in versions prior to 4.1 where you need to explicitly define indexes.

Answer (score 1):

One more reason to add:

> Different charset or engine will also cause this problem

Answer (score 0):

In my person experience this a very buggy characteristic of MySQL - and the least hassle is to just dump the table structure and data, then drop the table and re-run the SQL from the dump and then manually re-create indexes and foreign key constraints where needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a constraint with the same name in a different table.
Try changing the name of your constraint.