# Mysql error no 105 , when creating a foriegn key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have Two tables: `sys_users` and `sys_roles`.

After creating two tables I tried to create foreign keys with the following statement:

```
Alter table `hr_001`.`sys_users`
add constraint
`constraint_user_role` foreign key (`Role`) references
`hr_001`.`sys_roles`(`ID`) on delete Set null
```

But it gives me the following error

> Query: Alter table `hr_001`.`sys_users` add constraint
>   `constraint_user_role` foreign key (`Role`) references
>   `hr_001`.`sys_roles`(`ID`...
>
> ```
> Error Code: 1005
> Can't create table 'hr_001.#sql-2e5c_1f' (errno: 150)
> ```

My table creation statements are

```
CREATE TABLE `sys_users` (
    `ID` INT (10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Username` VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    `Password` VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    `Active` TINYINT (1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `Role` INT (11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT = 2 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE `sys_roles` (
    `ID` INT (10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Role` VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT = 2 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Please post the `create table code` of those two tables.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825362/mysql-error-150-foreign-keys

Comment: but i think this is what you should look first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233032/mysql-error-150-cannot-create-table

Comment: @1000111
create statements

CREATE TABLE `sys_roles` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Role` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `sys_users` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `Role` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: @1000111   look at my edited question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your foreign key creation syntax using not `ON DELETE SET NULL` but on `ON DELETE CASCADE` if your reference is created then take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1233035/2560539) and check your tables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry i have forgot to alter the **sys_users** table **Role**
 column as **unsigned** , becouse **sys_roles** **id** column is marked as **unsigned**, Thank you guys for fast replies.

Comment: Yes that's the reason. You may also look at this [**post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018584/error-code-1005-cant-create-table-errno-150) to gather some knowledge on some known cases of foreign key error